# Trying to implement ObjectiveC protocol in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, inheritance

I am trying to implement the below protocol in Swift which is written in objective-c however I am still receiving compiler errors saying that the class does not conform to the protocol. What am I doing wrong? I have tried setting getters and setters and applying the @NSCopying flag but to no avail.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol AIConfiguration <NSObject>

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSURL *baseURL;

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *clientAccessToken;

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *subscriptionKey;

@end
```

Here is my implementation

```
class AIMyConfiguration : NSObject, AIConfiguration {

    var baseURL : NSURL
    var clientAccessToken : NSString
    var subscriptionKey : NSString

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Objective-C properties are very different from Swift instance variables.  Have you tried adding a getter and setter method that match what Objective-C's properties actually create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Objective-C protocol:

```
@protocol AIConfiguration <NSObject>
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSURL *baseURL;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *clientAccessToken;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *subscriptionKey;
@end
```

is translated to Swift as:

```
protocol AIConfiguration : NSObjectProtocol {
    @NSCopying var baseURL: NSURL! { get set }
    var clientAccessToken: String! { get set }
    var subscriptionKey: String! { get set }
}
```

So you have to implement like:

as `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`

```
class AIMyConfiguration: NSObject, AIConfiguration {
    @NSCopying var baseURL: NSURL!
    var clientAccessToken: String!
    var subscriptionKey: String!

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

OR as `Optional`:

```
class AIMyConfiguration: NSObject, AIConfiguration {
    @NSCopying var baseURL: NSURL?
    var clientAccessToken: String?
    var subscriptionKey: String?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

OR non optional:

```
class AIMyConfiguration: NSObject, AIConfiguration {
    @NSCopying var baseURL: NSURL
    var clientAccessToken: String
    var subscriptionKey: String

    init(baseURL:NSURL, clientAccessToken:String, subscriptionKey:String) {
        self.baseURL = baseURL
        self.clientAccessToken = clientAccessToken
        self.subscriptionKey = subscriptionKey
        super.init()
    }
}
```